# fragment's onActivityForResult is not response, specific as fllow

Tags: android, fragment, onactivityresult

Has a MainActvity,the fragment is inside. The Fragment startActivityForResult to another Activity,and get data setResult() to the Fragment. The Mainctivity's launchMode is defult.
But,the Fragment's Method onActivityForResult() is not implement.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to call `super.onActivityResult` in your MainActivity if you override `onActivityResult`

That's the most common mistake but there are more cases which are covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment)